# mySQL: Compare current password and then update to new password in 1 query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm writing a script in PHP to allow a user to change their password.  I make them enter their old password (even if they are logged in already) and then the new password.  I'm trying to compare the old password and then update the field to the new password without running two separate queries, but my code isn't working like I expected.  Is there a bug here?  Or is this not allowed for some reason?  What do you suggest?

`mysql_query("UPDATE users SET userpass = '$encryptedPW' WHERE userid = '$uid' AND userpass = '$currentPW'");`

I could see if mySQL performed the tasks in the order they're written, but it has to *find* the line before it can *update* it, right?

Thank you very much!

Billy

ETA:  Sorry!  Typo!

Comment: you are setting `userpass`, but your where clause has a different column name: `user_pass`?

Comment: Oh, and yes, I will increase the encryption to hash() and add salt once I get it working. =)  TIA!

Comment: @Stew Sorry, that was just a typo.  Thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the actual generated query look like? Did you check if the query query succeeded?

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE ....") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_affected_rows() != 1) {
   die("Failed to change password");
}
```

The `or die()` portion will handle any sql syntax errors, while the affected_rows will check if something did get updated. If the affected row count isn't 1 (assuming you're not allowing duplicate username/password pairs), then something didn't work right. 0 = no affected rows, no changes made. >1 = you've got duplicate user/password pairs.

Also make sure that you're comparin apples to apples. If you're storing the passwords in encrypted/hashed form, then you'll have to compare hashed/encrypted passwords for the results to make sense.

```
... WHERE password='letmein'
```

would fail if the password is actually stored as encrypted binary garbage.

Comment: Oooh, good questions.  I'll check that shortly and get back to you.  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: +1, But I don't agree with your handling affected_rows > 1. If that happens, 'Failed to change password' is not correct message (password was actually changed). In my opinion, it should be a unique constrain on `username`, so affected rows cannot be greater than 1 .

Comment: @a1ex07: I'm not going to write out error handlers for every case. That's beyond the scope of fixing the OP's immediately issue.

Comment: @MarcB OK, I'm not totally familiar with what you're talking about, but I ran `UPDATE users SET userpass = 'test' WHERE userid = '23' AND userpass = 'oldpass'` and it worked just fine!  So, apparently  it's not my mySQL.

I wasn't using the die() operator before, but I see how helpful it can be.

I did make sure I'm comparing apples to apples.

Thanks for helping me diagnose this.  I'll post more information if the answer isn't apparent to me now that I know the mySQL isn't the issue.

Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I ran that query through phpmyAdmin.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  I found the problem... stupid mistake.  Thank you all for your help in diagnosing this though... I definitely learned a few things!

Answer (score 0):

from your code, I see that you use encrypted passwords. Check that you encrypted both passwords. 
Furthermore, you have userpass and user_pass in your query. These are two "different" columns.

Comment: Thanks.  I did check that and the user_pass vs userpass was a typo.  I appreciate your reply though!

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea here, but I would advise against (for security concerns) using `mysql_query()` with unfiltered input. I'd rather see you using a prepared statement.

From your above query, however, it seems as if you have two different columns, `user_pass` and `userpass`. That may be the source of your woes for now.

Comment: Man, you guys are so fast on that user_pass thing! =)  It was just a typo.  Regarding the unfiltered input, I am using `mysql_real_escape_string()` on the input.  Does that address your concern?